Output of TIP122 drops when connecting a load
I have built this circuit:

(the components here are labeled wrong LM317LZ is LM317T and TIP122G is TIP122)
When there is no load the output of TIP122 is 10V-20V (when adjusting potentiometer) which is intended. However when connecting the motor which is rated 20V 2.2A the output drops to 2-5mV. I've doing Rb (R5) calculations as decribed here and here. I've also tried guessing the resistance from very small values (10-100Ohm) and very large values (100k-500kOhm) however nothing that I've done works. Have I missed something somewhere else?
Edit:
I started off with a scheme that had no LM317T, the 555 was connected to 12V and output pin was switching TIP122 and the motor was connected to the same 12V, everything worked fine. Then I modified the scheme in the way that is in the picture and it stopped working.
Some tests I've done: 1. the motor runs ok with 12V and 20V, 2. I tested the circuit with some chinese 20V (unknown A) drill motor (the main motor RS775-20V is from lidl drill) that was smaller in size than the main one the output was only 0.02-0.06mV
I couldn't complete connecting 12V or 20V to Rb test because somepart of the circuit broke, I'm getting 20V on 555, 0V out, I'll need to buy more components to resolder this circuit. Sorry
Edit2:
The problem was caused by faulty TIP122. Replacing both TIP122 and 555 (which I broke during testing and most likely wasn't causing the problem in the first place) resolved the issue.

Sorry for the lack of details. I wanted to form the question in the way to ask what Rb to pick. I'm adding an edit to this post because all the details couldn't fit in the comment.

Thanks. Very much appreciated. When you get some more components, that will help out, perhaps. I think you should perform your tests progressively. So start with the motor, make sure it works. (You've done that.) then add the Darlington transistor and the base resistor, with the motor and the diode, and test again. Using either 12 V or 20 V (doesn't matter really) to the base resistor. If it works, then you have verified that this part of the circuit is working. That's important.

I am grateful for you for taking your time to help me. Replacing TIP122 and 555 fixed my problems. Thank you again.

You probably need these:

A bypass capacitor very close to Q1 and D3, of large size, reduces supply fluctuations to a reasonable value.  You don't mention what the supply is or how it's wired, but even a meter of cable length could be consequential, and an electrolytic capacitor solves that, probably a modestly large one like 1000uF.  Likewise, the 555 draws large peak currents from the 12V regulator, and some capacitance is needed, I would say 1uF minimum, or 10uF+ if electrolytic.
Note that this circuit has no current limiting, and a "drill motor" can easily draw over the 5A a TIP122 is rated for, let alone the 1A a 1N4007 is rated for; overloading the circuit will quickly overheat and blow the transistor, and likely diode too.

Thank you for your suggestion. I resoldered my original circuit with brand new components and it works perfectly now, so most likely TIP122 was faulty. I tested the circuit before adding current limiting resistor to my motor, TIP122 blew up. I then added 6Ohm 20W which I know is bad and I'll change it when I'll buy new ones. The powersupply is drill battery, which is close to the circuit (~30cm of cable) and is wired through switch and 5A fuse.

I'll be modifying the circuit by adding your suggested capacitors. However I have a question: should the 1000uF cap be on the board next to TIP122 or on the motor? Because motor is wired ~50cm from the board.
I really appreciate your suggestion, thank you again.

Q1, D3 and cap should be co-located.

OK. Got it. Thank you.
